# Matlab cftool giving a terrible fit for a simple graph

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I'm trying to do a fit on `cftool` for the movement of an oscillator in steady state.  I've entered start points as accurately as I can, but Matlab keeps giving a terrible fit (R² is negative.)  This, though it's clear even visually that a better fit can be had.
By changing the upper and lower bounds, I can force the graph into a better fit.  But it's still not 100%, Matlab keeps giving a negative R², and when I take off the bounds, it returns to a worse fit.
Current fit:
[image: image of fit]

Data added upon request:

```
t1_w10_a5_ss:

8
8.05000000000000
8.10000000000000
8.15000000000000
8.20000000000000
8.25000000000000
8.30000000000000
8.35000000000000
8.40000000000000
8.45000000000000
8.50000000000000
8.55000000000000
8.60000000000000
8.65000000000000
8.70000000000000
8.75000000000000
8.80000000000000
8.85000000000000
8.90000000000000
8.95000000000000
9
9.05000000000000
9.10000000000000
9.15000000000000
9.20000000000000
9.25000000000000
9.30000000000000
9.35000000000000
9.40000000000000
9.45000000000000
9.50000000000000
9.55000000000000
9.60000000000000
9.65000000000000
9.70000000000000
9.75000000000000
9.80000000000000
9.85000000000000
9.90000000000000
9.95000000000000
10
10.0500000000000
10.1000000000000
10.1500000000000
10.2000000000000
10.2500000000000
10.3000000000000
10.3500000000000
10.4000000000000
10.4500000000000
10.5000000000000
10.5500000000000
10.6000000000000
10.6500000000000
10.7000000000000
10.7500000000000
10.8000000000000
10.8500000000000
10.9000000000000

x1_w10_a5_ss:
0.191254400000000
0.192137400000000
0.190920000000000
0.190923800000000
0.190562700000000
0.191785800000000
0.191260200000000
0.191621400000000
0.190396400000000
0.191092000000000
0.191080500000000
0.192133600000000
0.191264000000000
0.191273600000000
0.190388800000000
0.191780000000000
0.191776200000000
0.192137400000000
0.190916200000000
0.191269700000000
0.190736600000000
0.191785800000000
0.191260200000000
0.191617600000000
0.190742300000000
0.191269700000000
0.190738500000000
0.191615700000000
0.190914300000000
0.191443700000000
0.190736600000000
0.191785800000000
0.191260200000000
0.191617600000000
0.190738500000000
0.191611800000000
0.191256300000000
0.191961600000000
0.191088200000000
0.191443700000000
0.190740400000000
0.191441700000000
0.190912400000000
0.191615700000000
0.190914300000000
0.191443700000000
0.190742300000000
0.191271700000000
0.190568400000000
0.191269700000000
0.190740400000000
0.191443700000000
0.190742300000000
0.191271700000000
0.190566500000000
0.191439800000000
0.191084400000000
0.191789600000000
0.190916200000000
```

Comment: May your should provide your data to give any help, BTW your data seems to be low-sampled / noisy

Comment: this is what we call junk in junk out. why do you think the model you have (a*cos(b*t+c)+d) represent the data you show? maybe you have some dumping (exp(-t\tau) ? or some chirp (cos(b*t+c*t^2) ? the sampling of the data is below the nyquist limit, so the only tool here that might work will be a soft L1 or L1 norm minimization, depends on how noisy the data is...

Comment: Most likely the problem is not scatter, but is related to oscillation  frequency and sampling frequency. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is a problem of software. I observed a similar difficulty with another software and different method of fitting.

At first glance this look like white noice :

[image]

But there is another possible (and more physical) explanation. If the sampling frequency is too low compare to the oscillating frequency this is typically the kind of data that is commonly observed.

I suppose that you can roughly evaluate the frequency of oscillation at steady state by direct measurement (not from your data). What is the order of magnitude of the frequency of oscillation ? This is a very important piece of information to explain what is really the problem and to suggest what to do.